# How to send form data to the server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am working with two servers, one for **React** (on address `http://localhost:3000/contact`) and another for **Express** (on address `http://localhost:5000/`). I want to send form data object through some HTTP request approach as a POST method but I get empty object on the "backend" side.

I have a simple form with an `onSubmit` event which firstly creates an object with the form data values:

```
const data = {
    firstInput: evt.target.elements.firstInput.value,
    secondInput: evt.target.elements.secondInput.value
}
```

**Note:** I tested If get all the data until here with DevTools and React Dev tools, until here it works great.

And the second server with Express that just have a simple endpoint which should receive this data or at least print what I sent in the `req.body` object:

```
server.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.end(req.body);
});
```

**Note 2:** Also tested this endpoint and it works fine but `req.body` gets an empty object.

I have tested several methods like:

> Native `fetch` API:
>
> ```
> fetch("http://localhost:5000/", {
>     method: "POST",
>     headers: {
>         Accept: "application/json",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json"
>     },
>     body: JSON.stringify(data)
>     }).then(res => {
>         console.log(res);
>     });
> ```
>
> ***Error***:
>
> [image: Error]

Also, tried with `async` / `await` approach on `fetch API` but I wasn't sure about using it on React component.

I also have tried [http API](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) but I got with the same.

I guess my first question is how to send properly formatted the data from the component side to the server side. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this package [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)
You can use like this:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
fetch('url here', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, // this line is important
    body: queryString.stringify({for:'bar', blah:1}
});
```